# MySql select value if confition match or select first if not match

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to select a user profile from a MySql database. I also have another table that contains user's telephone because they can have multiple phones. In the phones table I have a field called `main` to indicate it's a main contact.

So, a user may have 3 phones (or even more) but only 1 can be the main phone. When I'm selecting the user profile I need to verify if there is any phone marked as main phone and select this. In case there is no phone marked as `main` then I select the first from the list.

This is my phone table:

```
id | id_user | main | phone
15 | 23      | 0    | 99999999999
16 | 23      | 1    | 88888888888
17 | 27      | 0    | 66666666666
18 | 27      | 0    | 77777777777
```

So in the example above, I would need to select both users (23 and 27), the user 23 needs to have the phone `88888888888` and the user 27 needs to have the phone `66666666666`.

But I don't know how to achieve this, I was ale to select only the first register, this is my code so far:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, a.f_name, a.l_name, a.code,
    ( 
        SELECT phone FROM tb_phone WHERE id_user = a.id ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
    ) as 'phone'
FROM tb_user a
WHERE a.active = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is close:

```
SELECT u.*
       (SELECT p.phone
        FROM tb_phone p
        WHERE p.id_user = u.id
        ORDER BY p.main DESC, p.id
        LIMIT 1
       ) as phone
FROM tb_user u
WHERE u.active = 1;
```

In other words, you need to add `p.main` into the `ORDER BY`.

In addition, I changed the table aliases so they are abbreviations of the table names.  That makes the query much easier to follow.

Comment: It's funny how it was easier than I tought. Thanks for the answer!